# Why isn't my class being loaded through the external class loader?

Tags: java, class, classloader, external, classnotfoundexception

I want to run the constructor of the Main.class in the package Test2, located in the folder C:\classes\

This is the code I'm using. It throws a class not found exception when it tries to turn it into a class. And then once it's part of the class object, will the constructor automatically be run, or do I have to instance it somehow? Test2 is inputted into this code as text.

```
    if (Main.os.equals("Windows"))
    {
        String path = "C:\\classes\\";
    }
    else
    {
        String path = "~/classes/";
    }

    File file = new File(path);

    try
    {
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
        Main.print("Stage 1");
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Main.print("Stage 2");
        Class cls = cl.loadClass(text + ".Main");
        Main.print(text + " was loaded into memory.");
        close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete code of both classes?

Comment: This is the only part that pertains to the question... This code is in the ActionListener code for a dialog box that feeds it the variable text. The other class simply does a hello world println in the constructor.

Comment: That's not quite true. We also need the package and class declarations for Main. These are important. Additionally, we need the value of `text`. We can infer from your comment that text is "Test2", but we don't know!

Comment: It's all normal stuff, package Test2; public class Main. Text is set as a string by doing String text = name.getText(); where name is the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is one of the following:

1. `file` doesn't exist or hasn't been properly specified. Check via `file.exists()`
2. Your class file is not located in the correct directory. If the package declaration for the `Main` class is `package Test2;` then your class file must be in the following location: `C:\classes\Test2\Main.class`.
3. If Main is nested class, then you will need to refer to the enclosing class when loading it, eg `cl.loadClass("Test2.EnclosingClass$Main");`

My guess it that your problem is number 2! :)

Good luck.

Oh, and yes, you'll need to create an instance of your object if you want the constructor to be called: `clazz.newInstance()` is the simplest method for no-args constructors.

Comment: It's not 2 or 3... I'll check 1. Could Java not have permissions to access C:\classes?

Comment: Any idea how to put the new class instance on it's own thread?

Comment: Do you mean you wish for the new instance to have it's constructor invoked by another thread?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the exact error message.

But here is how I execute a main method of using a class loader

```
    urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    Class runClass = urlLoader.loadClass(classToRun);
    System.out.println("Starting Program !!!");

    Object[] arguments = new Object[]{args};
    Method mainMethod = runClass.getMethod("main", new Class[] {args.getClass()});
    mainMethod.invoke(null, arguments);
```

**Note:** *classToRun* will be the full package/class definition
i.e. **net.sf.RecordEditor.edit.FullEditor**

**Note:** I use it to load from jar files, it will be similar for directories

It is taken from  the run class here

http://record-editor.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/record-editor/Source/RecordEditor/src/net/sf/RecordEditor/utils/Run.java?revision=65&view=markup

An example of calling the class is here
http://record-editor.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/record-editor/Source/RecordEditor/src/net/sf/RecordEditor/RunFullEditor.java?revision=65&view=markup

Comment: The variable classToRun... in my code it is the same ClassLoader variable as urlLoader. Is that wrong?